# Pytorch summary : number of parameters

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am experimenting with various deep networks and I always want to know how may parameters are involved. I was using pytorch summary however I noticed that if I use many times the same module in the forward pass, its associated parameters are counted multiple times.

An example is this:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.lin = nn.Linear(3,3)

    def forward(self,x):
      x = self.lin(x)
      x = self.lin(x)
      x = self.lin(x)
      x = self.lin(x)
      return x
net = Net()
from torchsummary import summary
summary(net.to(device),(1,3))
```

where you get 48 Total params, which is 12*4. 12, in this case, is actually the number of trainable parameters of the network.

Thus, my question is, is there a way to make Pytorch summary print out the number of "single" trainable parameters of the model?

Otherwise, I know to use a script like this

```
model_parameters = filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, net.parameters())
params = sum([np.prod(p.size()) for p in model_parameters])
print(f"The network has {params} trainable parameters")
```

to get the desired result, but I like how pytorch summary works.

Answer (score 0):

From the [discussion here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/repeated-model-layers-real-or-torchsummary-bug/26489/2), it seems that [torchsummary](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary) (in its current form) is not created with all possible models in mind. It works mostly on very clean linear architectures since it uses [forward hooks](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary/blob/master/torchsummary/torchsummary.py#L52) for computing everything (including number of parameters).

This design choice is due to how dynamics PyTorch is which makes it hard to make it right for every possible models.

I guess for your case, its better to just use the way you mentioned at the end of your question.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I guess that in all recurrent neural networks this is the only possibility.